# Can't rename PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSql 9.2.
Trying to do

`ALTER DATABASE 3_8_dev_test6 RENAME TO 3_8_dev_test`

but get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "3"
LINE 1: ALTER DATABASE 3_8_dev_test6 RENAME TO 3_8_dev_test
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you created database with name starting with number? I thought database name cannot start with number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name really starts with a number then use double quotes

```
ALTER DATABASE "3_8_dev_test6" RENAME TO "3_8_dev_test"
```

But then you will have to match the case also

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2):

Postgres assumes you're going to enter a number in this case so if you want to have numbers in the beginning of a name, use quotes :)

In this case:

```
ALTER DATABASE "3_8_dev_test6" RENAME "TO 3_8_dev_test";
```